# ffmpeg running on windows with java

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I have simple test class as

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         String[] line = {"ffmpeg -i D:\\hadoop-video\\testVideo\\xyz.mp4 %d.png"};
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec(line);

    }
```

when I try to run this I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ffmpeg -i D:/hadoop-video/testVideo/xyz.mp4 %d.png": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at ImageTest.main(ImageTest.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

however file is present on my windows7 machine with location

```
D:\hadoop-video\testVideo\xyz.mp4
```

i tried removing .mp4 and then run also not working . please suggest what might be wrong

Answer (score 2):

Where ffmpeg.exe is installed? try to use full path to execute the ffmpeg.exe

e.g.

D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe

then

```
String cmd[] = {"D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg","-i","D:\\ffmpeg\\hadoop.mp4","D:\\ffmpeg\\img%d.png"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

or

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(cmd)).start();
```

Comment: I added full path as below                                    String[] line = {"C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i D:\\hadoop-video\\testVideo\\xyz.mp4 %d.png"};
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(line); still not working .

Comment: error i am getting is as Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i D:\hadoop-video\testVideo\xyz %d.png": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
 at ImageTest.main(ImageTest.java:14)

Comment: String[] line = {"C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg", "-i", "D:\\hadoop-video\\testVideo\\xyz", "%d.png"};
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(line); Now no error is coming however Images are also not getting generated

Comment: Check your project directory in eclipse workspace, this will have all generated images ;)

Comment: Hey Thanks .. its there in Eclipse . i was trying to search in the video folder ..Can we customize the location . thanks one more time :) cheers